# Difference between third-person forms of "go"

Tags: present-tense

> "goes" Third person singular present tense of go.
>
> "goes" Third-person singular simple present indicative form of go.

What is the difference between these parts of speech? Could you provide an example of each?

Answer (score 0):

Those are equivalent.  *Indicative mood* is used in a sentence that makes a statement or asks a question.

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indicative_mood.htm